# MatplotLib (TKinter) + OpenCV crashing in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to run some Python 3 code which first shows an OpenCV window and when it closes it should plot something using MatplotLib. However upon the `plt.show()` call the program crashes: **python3.6 quit unexpectedly.**

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")     # <== Doesn't solve the problem
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cv2
#cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)  <== Doesn't solve the problem

im = np.zeros((100,100,3))
cv2.imshow('test', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)

plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0,20,200)))
plt.show()                  # <== Crashes on this call
```

In other StackOverflow posts I found setting the MatplotLib backend to `TkAgg` should fix this or setting `setUseOpenCL(false)`. However both these potential fixes do not work on my MacBook. I've tried several things, like changing the import order, trying to swap the MatplotLib backend. Anyone has an idea on how to fix this problem?

**MacOS Sierra** 10.12.3
**Python** 3.6.0
**TKinter** Version 8.5
**OpenCV** Version 3.2.0
**MatplotLib** Version 2.0.0

The stacktrace of how it crashes:

**libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

> 2017-03-28 11:30:45.639 python3.6[5208:78361] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f997ec98190
>   2017-03-28 11:30:45.641 python3.6[5208:78361] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f997ec98190'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffbeb80e7b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffd3760cad objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffbec02cb4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffbeaf2fb5 ___forwarding_** + 1061
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffbeaf2b08 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   Tk                                  0x00000001032c45e6 TkpInit + 471
>       6   Tk                                  0x000000010323fc8d Tk_Init + 1794
>       7   _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x000000010311cde6 Tcl_AppInit + 82
>       8   _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x00000001031183a3 _tkinter_create + 1094
>       9   Python                              0x0000000100b28ea2 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 172
>       10  Python                              0x0000000100b927a2 call_function + 584
>       11  Python                              0x0000000100b8fbbb _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23930
>       12  Python                              0x0000000100b92fbf _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1973
>       13  Python                              0x0000000100b938c4 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 477
>       14  Python                              0x0000000100aeea73 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 231
>       15  Python                              0x0000000100aeeb93 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 149
>       16  Python                              0x0000000100aee8cb PyObject_Call + 102
>       17  Python                              0x0000000100b3cd24 slot_tp_init + 61
>       18  Python                              0x0000000100b39ac3 type_call + 184
>       19  Python                              0x0000000100aeea34 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 168
>       20  Python                              0x0000000100b9263b call_function + 225
>       21  Python                              0x0000000100b8fbbb _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23930
>       22  Python                              0x0000000100b93976 _PyFunction_FastCall + 122
>       23  Python                              0x0000000100b92775 call_function + 539
>       24  Python                              0x0000000100b8fbbb _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23930
>       25  Python                              0x0000000100b92fbf _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1973
>       26  Python                              0x0000000100b89e02 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 100
>       27  Python                              0x0000000100b101e3 function_call + 363
>       28  Python                              0x0000000100aee8cb PyObject_Call + 102
>       29  Python                              0x0000000100b8fe16 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 24533
>       30  Python                              0x0000000100b92fbf _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1973
>       31  Python                              0x0000000100b936da fast_function + 241
>       32  Python                              0x0000000100b92775 call_function + 539
>       33  Python                              0x0000000100b8fbbb _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23930
>       34  Python                              0x0000000100b93976 _PyFunction_FastCall + 122
>       35  Python                              0x0000000100b92775 call_function + 539
>       36  Python                              0x0000000100b8fbbb _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23930
>       37  Python                              0x0000000100b92fbf _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1973
>       38  Python                              0x0000000100b936da fast_function + 241
>       39  Python                              0x0000000100b92775 call_function + 539
>       40  Python                              0x0000000100b8fbbb _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23930
>       41  Python                              0x0000000100b92fbf _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1973
>       42  Python                              0x0000000100b936da fast_function + 241
>       43  Python                              0x0000000100b92775 call_function + 539
>       44  Python                              0x0000000100b8fbbb _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23930
>       45  Python                              0x0000000100b92fbf _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1973
>       46  Python                              0x0000000100b89d98 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
>       47  Python                              0x0000000100bb33aa run_mod + 58
>       48  Python                              0x0000000100bb36bf PyRun_FileExFlags + 178
>       49  Python                              0x0000000100bb2d58 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 676
>       50  Python                              0x0000000100bc74d0 Py_Main + 3472
>       51  python3.6                           0x0000000100adfe17 python3.6 + 7703
>       52  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffd4044255 start + 1
>       53  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
>   )

Comment: Seems to be a Mac problem. I cannot reproduce this on windows where it works as expected.

Comment: Not a Mac problem. The code runs fine on my mac without "TkAgg" and does generate the same error with `matplotlib.use("TkAgg") `.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue on a Mac with OpenCV 3.2.0.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you figure out the solution

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it will help you guys/girls, but I ran into similar issues trying to embed matplotlib into a kivy application (Also on a mac), after a few hours of googling, rewriting classes, uninstalls and reinstalls, and at one point even attempting to plot using a different library entirely. I found the simplest solution was to to bin off the ('TkAgg') backend entirely as it doesn't seem to play nice and then explicitly declare the OSX one

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("MacOSX")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Worked for me, Occams razor and all that I suppose, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No idea about matplotlib, but I can imagine that there could be a problem with window management. Try this:

```
cv2.imshow('test', im)
cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyWindow('test')
```

At least this is the right way of treating already opened cv2.imshow() windows when they are not used anymore.

Comment: Not sure about verified.human, but I have the same problem and this doesn't fix it for me.