# tkinter crashes on ipython, but not in python (on a M1 Mac)

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, ipython, tk-toolkit

I am using a miniconda installation on an M1 Mac and `tkinter crashes when I call it from` ipython`, but not from` python`. Here's example code that leads to the crash:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showerror('a','b')
```

Running this from the python interpreter (at `~/miniforge3/bin/`) works, but from ipython (same path) causes a crash back to terminal:

```
2022-04-21 14:19:39.873 python[56056:2463981] -[NSApplication macOSVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11d627510
2022-04-21 14:19:39.876 python[56056:2463981] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication macOSVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11d627510'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000192b76b08 __exceptionPreprocess + 240
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001928c1e14 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000192c0aa68 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000192ad5e14 ___forwarding___ + 1764
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000192ad5670 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
    5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c3ef918 GetRGBA + 264
    6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c3ef728 TkpGetColor + 648
    7   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c33a1cc Tk_GetColor + 168
    8   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c32b4e0 Tk_Get3DBorder + 152
    9   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c32b320 Tk_Alloc3DBorderFromObj + 144
    10  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c33b77c DoObjConfig + 848
    11  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c33b334 Tk_InitOptions + 372
    12  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c33b218 Tk_InitOptions + 88
    13  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c3683e0 CreateFrame + 1480
    14  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c36870c TkListCreateFrame + 172
    15  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012c360f68 Initialize + 1856
    16  _tkinter.cpython-39-darwin.so       0x000000012af6e078 Tkapp_New + 876
    17  _tkinter.cpython-39-darwin.so       0x000000012af6d9a0 _tkinter_create + 596
    18  python3.9                           0x00000001025f827c cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 208
    19  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    20  python3.9                           0x00000001026afd44 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29268
    21  python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    22  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3e64 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 240
    23  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3468 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 320
    24  python3.9                           0x00000001025a41e0 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 164
    25  python3.9                           0x000000010261dbb4 slot_tp_init + 380
    26  python3.9                           0x000000010262c658 type_call + 344
    27  python3.9                           0x00000001025a31e8 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 340
    28  python3.9                           0x00000001026b36ac call_function + 724
    29  python3.9                           0x00000001026afdc4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29396
    30  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3ee4 function_code_fastcall + 116
    31  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    32  python3.9                           0x00000001026afdc4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29396
    33  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3ee4 function_code_fastcall + 116
    34  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    35  python3.9                           0x00000001026afd44 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29268
    36  python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    37  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3e64 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 240
    38  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    39  python3.9                           0x00000001026afd44 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29268
    40  python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    41  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3e64 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 240
    42  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3468 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 320
    43  python3.9                           0x00000001025a41e0 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 164
    44  python3.9                           0x000000010261dbb4 slot_tp_init + 380
    45  python3.9                           0x000000010262c658 type_call + 344
    46  python3.9                           0x00000001025a31e8 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 340
    47  python3.9                           0x00000001026b36ac call_function + 724
    48  python3.9                           0x00000001026afdc4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29396
    49  python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    50  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3e64 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 240
    51  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    52  python3.9                           0x00000001026afd28 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29240
    53  python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    54  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3e64 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 240
    55  python3.9                           0x00000001026b0078 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30088
    56  python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    57  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3e64 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 240
    58  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    59  python3.9                           0x00000001026afd44 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29268
    60  python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    61  python3.9                           0x00000001026a3020 builtin_exec + 1032
    62  python3.9                           0x00000001025f827c cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 208
    63  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    64  python3.9                           0x00000001026afdc4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29396
    65  python3.9                           0x00000001025ba04c gen_send_ex + 532
    66  python3.9                           0x00000001026ac37c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 14476
    67  python3.9                           0x00000001025ba04c gen_send_ex + 532
    68  python3.9                           0x00000001026ac37c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 14476
    69  python3.9                           0x00000001025ba04c gen_send_ex + 532
    70  python3.9                           0x00000001025b0cbc method_vectorcall_O + 160
    71  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    72  python3.9                           0x00000001026afd28 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29240
    73  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3ee4 function_code_fastcall + 116
    74  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    75  python3.9                           0x00000001026afdc4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29396
    76  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3ee4 function_code_fastcall + 116
    77  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    78  python3.9                           0x00000001026afd28 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29240
    79  python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    80  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3e64 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 240
    81  python3.9                           0x00000001025a6cf0 method_vectorcall + 164
    82  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    83  python3.9                           0x00000001026afe40 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29520
    84  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3ee4 function_code_fastcall + 116
    85  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    86  python3.9                           0x00000001026afd28 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29240
    87  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3ee4 function_code_fastcall + 116
    88  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    89  python3.9                           0x00000001026afd28 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29240
    90  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3ee4 function_code_fastcall + 116
    91  python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    92  python3.9                           0x00000001026afd28 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29240
    93  python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    94  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3e64 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 240
    95  python3.9                           0x00000001025a6cf0 method_vectorcall + 164
    96  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3a5c PyVectorcall_Call + 156
    97  python3.9                           0x00000001026b0078 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30088
    98  python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    99  python3.9                           0x00000001025a3e64 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 240
    100 python3.9                           0x00000001026b3614 call_function + 572
    101 python3.9                           0x00000001026afdc4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29396
    102 python3.9                           0x00000001026a84a8 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2968
    103 python3.9                           0x000000010270b834 pyrun_file + 376
    104 python3.9                           0x000000010270ad48 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 816
    105 python3.9                           0x000000010272de84 Py_RunMain + 2916
    106 python3.9                           0x000000010272f018 pymain_main + 1272
    107 python3.9                           0x0000000102549ddc main + 56
    108 dyld                                0x0000000102a75088 start + 516
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

Just a call to `tkinter.Tk()` gives the same. I get the same if I use `python --gui 'tk'`. Any idea how to solve or at least debug this?

**Edit:**
I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066073/matplotlib-tkinter-opencv-crashing-in-python-3) which reminded me that I import `matplotlib.pyplot` upon the startup of `ipython`. Turning this off fixed it. But if someone can elaborate why this is or how to *really* fix it, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to explicitly set `matplotlib` to use TK:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
```

My hypothesis is that IPython loads matplotlib, and that MPL by default uses a different UI backend, and that loading two UI backends causes trouble.